# Composite Application Framework Equivalent in Java

Tags: java, composite, prism

Just wondering what the opposing framework in Java would be for creating modular GUI applications, with things like event aggregation, etc.

I know for Java there isn't a single definitive GUI framework, and so far I've seen the Eclipse RCP and Netbeans Platform, however these don't seem to do these kind of things.

I'm a .Net developer looking to transition across to Java, and please excuse my ignorance if the question doesn't make complete sense.

Comment: I'd check out Spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for application frameworks or rich client platforms, so Eclipse RCP if the right direction.

Eclipse builds on OSGI and that means that any module (called Eclipse Plug-In or OSGi Bundle) can either register its own services or makeuse of any other service provided by any other module. The Eclipse RCP platform comes with a lot of handy services, esp. in the meaning of Workbench-level services like `ISelectionService` where you can hook in to retrieve selection events. These selection events are already on a higher abstraction level, they don't contain mouse x/y coordinates but merely the Object(s) being selected such as a "Java Source File" in the Eclipse JDT case. There are menu manager services , selection services, event handling services, administration services, preferences services, action and command handler services etc.

If i understand event aggregation correctly, it manages a list of events and subscribers, and manages the forwarding of these events to whoever has subscribed to a given event.
This seems basically what Eclipse already covers under the hood, e.g. with the [OSGi EventAdmin](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/event/EventAdmin.html), but this is very low level.